# Facebook oAuth user varification

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using FB Oauth login first time for my application. My confusion is if a user login first time or second time. In a oauth login scenario:

If every time user login

1. How will I know that user is new ?
2. How will I know that logged user is not new ?
3. Is user logged in ?

To do all these things what are the things I will have to check on my own server side ?

In FB doc i saw `FB.getLoginStatus.` but i want to double check on my server side also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your server side is but I think you might want the Facebook Redirect Login Helper functions:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/4.0.0